# convert array to CSV file on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database, csv

Given array:

```
a = [[111,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"],[123,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"]]
```

And I want to convert this array to a new CSV file **WITH NEW COLUMNS** which would look like:

```
user_id | created_at
--------------------
111     | Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00
123     | Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00
```

How can I do this in Ruby? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sanfor but I guess my question is a bit different because mine includes to generate new columns.

Comment: provided array is not valid. it should be like this `a = [[111,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"],[123,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"]]`

Comment: @gagangami corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this **with**(2nd edit) proper indentation

```
headers = ["user_id", "created_at"]
CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w", :col_sep => "\t| ", :headers => true) do |csv|
  csv << headers
  csv << ["-"*(headers.join.length+4*headers.length)] #Header separator in the length of header columns + tabs
  a.each {|row| csv << row } #Adding rows for each element of a
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def export
  array = [[111,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"],[123,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"]]

  csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
   csv << [ "id","created_at"]
   array.each do |array|
     csv << [array[0],array[1]]
   end 
  end 
  send_data(csv_data, :type => 'text/csv', :filename => 'data.csv')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make method in model, i hope this will work for you. Tested from me. Working as you want.

```
CSV.generate(option) do |csv|
  csv << ['user_id', 'created_at']
    [[111,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"],[123,"Tue, 30 Jun 2015 23:50:55 KST +09:00"]].each do |array|
      csv << array
  end
end
```